# Bluetooth dongle problem.(probably regarding the driver)

Tags: drivers, lubuntu, bluetooth

I bought a Bluetooth dongle last week so I can use it on my laptop which runs Lubuntu 19.04. I tried it on my Win10 desktop and it works with only the generic Bluetooth driver installed but it just doesn't get recognized by blueman on my laptop.

On my Lubuntu machine I have installed bluetooth bluez bluez-tools and blueman. rfkill did not stop any connection. blueman shows an empty list in the adapters option. Bluedevil does not work at all("Breeze" error). I have rebooted the machine a couple times but none of those works. There is no option for bluetooth in the BIOS. The Bluetooth indicator/button on my laptop cannot be turned on.

output from `lsusb | grep Blue` found the Bluetooth dongle:

`Bus 005 Device 003: ID 0a12:0001 Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd Bluetooth Dongle (HCI mode)`

output from `dmesg | grep Blue` and `dmesg | grep USB`(Updated lines)

```
[   44.493848] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[   44.493895] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   44.495480] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   44.495485] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   44.495495] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   89.713691] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   89.713694] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   89.713702] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
```

```
[114740.910186] usb 5-1: new full-speed USB device number 5 using uhci_hcd
[114741.088279] usb 5-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0a12, idProduct=0001, bcdDevice=88.91
[114741.088283] usb 5-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[114741.088285] usb 5-1: Product: USB1.1-A
```

output from `hciconfig -a hci0`

```
hci0:   Type: Primary  Bus: USB
        BD Address: 00:1A:7D:DA:71:11  ACL MTU: 679:9  SCO MTU: 48:16
        DOWN 
        RX bytes:574 acl:0 sco:0 events:30 errors:0
        TX bytes:368 acl:0 sco:0 commands:30 errors:0
        Features: 0xff 0xff 0xcd 0xfa 0xdb 0xbf 0x7b 0x87
        Packet type: DM1 DM3 DM5 DH1 DH3 DH5 HV1 HV2 HV3 
        Link policy: RSWITCH HOLD SNIFF PARK 
        Link mode: SLAVE ACCEPT
```

I think it has something to do with the driver since the packaging did not list Linux as a compatible OS. I also have no idea how a driver works but since I "know" C and C++. I think I can so something about it.(Even though I don't know its architecture and I didn't learn asm)

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `usb-devices | awk '/0a12/' RS=`

Comment: @R3G3N3R4T0R: Please head over to https://askubuntu.com/questions/1205962/bluetooth-dongle-problem . Out of the 2 images and 4 products shown which (if any) does match the Bluetooth dongle you have? I am currently trying to assemble a patch that covers as many of these dongles as possible. Thank you for your help.